# HttpSessionListener events not invoking with Grails 1.3.7 and WLS

Tags: grails, weblogic11g

I have an application that is successfully deploying on tomcat, which I must migrate to running on Weblogic Server, however when I try to deploy there is a listener registered in the web.xml that is not firing. Is there some additional configuration needed for WLS to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this was a false alarm. WLS seems more agressive than Tomcat as to when it generates the http session so some replumbing later the session listener actually is firing successfully.